# What's the difference between Minimmum Spanning Tree and Travelling Salesman Problems

Tags: algorithm

Can we solve the Traveling Salesman Problem by finding the Minimum Spanning Tree?

Comment: There is a connection: they're both looking for a way to connect all vertices in a graph using the minimum edge weight. The difference is that MST looks for a tree while TSP looks for a path.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph, that is wrong - there is a connection, and the question makes sense:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960206.html
"A less obvious application is that the minimum spanning tree can be used to approximately solve the traveling salesman problem"

Comment: ... so, the answer to the question is:
No, not exactly, but you can solve the TSP approximately using a MSP:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960206.html
"[...] if you draw a path tracing around the minimum spanning tree, you trace each edge twice and visit all points, so the TSP weight is less than twice the MST weight. Therefore this tour is within a factor of two of optimal"

Comment: MST is a relaxed problem of TSP, So you can use MST solution as a heuristic function for TSP, Because It always estimate a solution with less cost than real solution. Your question's answer is "no". you can't use MST solutions for TSP.

Comment: No, In Tsp each vertices visited one time ,while in MST each node may visited many times . In other words ,in Tsp degree of node is 2 but in MST degree of node may be larger than 2

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Minimum Spanning Tree problem asks you to build a tree that connects all cities and has minimum total weight, while the Travelling Salesman Problem asks you to find a trip that visits all cities with minimum total weight (and possibly coming back to your starting point).

If you're having trouble seeing the difference, in MST, you need to find a minimum weight *tree* in a weighted graph, while in TSP you need to find a minimum weight *path* (or *cycle / circuit*). Does that help?

Comment: So If there is only one path between vertices, will it become TSP problem

Answer (score 6):

It's the difference between

> Finding an **acyclic connected subgraph** T of G with V(T) = V(G) and Weight(T) is minimal

and

> Finding a **cycle** C in G such that V(C) = V(G) and Weight(C) is minimal

where Weight(X) = Sum of edges of X. As you can see these two problems are pretty different.

Yet, there is a relation between the two. If the graph weights satisfy the triangle inequality, one can use the MST to approximate the TSP within a factor of x2: compute the MST, then traverse it (from any root) and return the vertices in a pre-order. You can find the detailed analysis of this approximation (as well as other approximations) in [The traveling salesman problem: An overview of exact and approximate algorithms by G Laporte - European Journal of Operational Research, 1992 - Elsevier](http://web.ist.utl.pt/%7Eist11038/CD_Casquilho/TSP1992EJOR_Laporte.pdf).